# Is sluggishly progressing schizophrenia recognized outside of Russia?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, psychiatry, schizophrenia

I've been trying to look up information about *sluggishly progressing schizophrenia*, but the only source accessible to me was a Wikipedia article, that states that the term “sluggish schizophrenia” was created to diagnose political dissidents, but nevertheless, it has been also adopted in modern Russia.

I wish to know about other countries, which haven't been a part of USSR. **Is the term officially recognized in the western world? Is it considered a complete misdiagnosis? Is there some other classification, that is used for the same condition instead?**

Answer (score 1):

The idea that schizo type disorders may onset slowly is commonly accepted in the West. We do not have a separate diagnosis for this type of onset in the DSM. Psychotic episodes may happen to individuals before they experience all the symptoms of bipolar or schizo type disorders.

It is common that a patient may begin to hear voices during isolated instances without the trouble with emotions. Then develop trouble with emotions. Then progress into hallucinations. The individual may cope with the isolated psychosis until the psychosis becomes so severe that they are unable to do without medical attention. This progression sometimes takes years.

It is possible that any diagnosis of mental illness can be used for political reasons though.